# How to get user group information from Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Microsoft Graph for fetching user information, namely ["List users" API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list).

Following is the code for accessing the user information :

```
  ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
  AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCred);
  string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
  Debug.WriteLine("token=" + token);   

  var responseString = String.Empty;
  string[] scopes = { "User.Read" };

  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    string requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,givenName,surname";

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    Debug.WriteLine(request.ToString());

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

    responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
  }
```

Output :

```
 {    
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,givenName,surname)",
"value": [
    {
        "id": "000000000-0000-0000-000-000000000",
        "givenName": "XXX",
        "surname": "XXX"
    }, {
        "id": "000000000-0000-0000-000-000000000",
        "givenName": "XXX",
        "surname": "XXX"
    }
]
 }
```

How to the get user group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [user: getMemberGroups API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) action for a user to get their groups:

You need to make a request like so:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id-here/getMemberGroups
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 33

{
  "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```

The `securityEnabledOnly` parameter defines if it should only return security groups. Setting it to false will also return the user's Office 365 group memberships for example.

An alternative is to use the `memberOf` navigation property:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id-here/memberOf
```

This returns the groups and directory roles the user is a *direct member* of.